# Issue with resetting data with a do while loop (Java)

Tags: java, loops, repeat

I'm working on a program for school where I need to sort how many vowels are in a string along with the # of non-vowels. My teacher wants us to ask the user if they want to continue so we can provide multiple test cases without running the program more than once. I successfully got the program to loop, but my problem is that the vowel and non-vowel numbers from the previous test case carry over to the next one. I've been searching around online for the solution but I've had no luck so far. Any help would be much appreciated. (I am a noob at programming btw, I still have much to learn.)

```html
import java.util.*;

class VowelReader
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String line;
    int vi= 0, a = 0, e = 0, o = 0, u = 0, nonvowels = 0;
    String answer = null;
   

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    
 do {   
    System.out.println("Enter a String to be processed for vowels: ");
    line = scan.nextLine( );
    
    for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
    char c = Character.toLowerCase(line.charAt(i));
    switch (c)
    {
      case 'a':
         a++;
        break;
      case 'e':
        e++;
        break;
      case 'i':
        vi++;
        break;
      case 'o':
        o++;
        break;
      case 'u':
        u++;
      default:
       nonvowels++;
        break;
        }
     }
    System.out.println(line); 
    System.out.println("a- " +a);
    System.out.println("e- " +e);
    System.out.println("i- " +vi);
    System.out.println("o- " +o);
    System.out.println("u- " +u);
    System.out.println("Non-vowels -" +nonvowels);
    
    System.out.println("Continue?(Y/N)");
       answer = scan.nextLine();
       }
       while( answer.toLowerCase().equals( "y" ) );
              
     }
}
```

Comment: You could literally just set them to 0 at the end of the loop. A better way would be to place the loop code in it's own function, and have it return the vowel counts.

Comment: Ok, I apologize for my incompetence, but how would I reset the variables if they are already defined in main?

Comment: If you were to put the code in it's own function, they would be defined inside the function, and automatically destroyed when the function exits. You would `return` a copy of the vowel counts to the `main`. Have you learn how to use functions to return?

Comment: No, I haven't learned how to do that yet unfortunately. But I will look into it on YouTube if I can. I don't want to take much more of your time from you. I really appreciate the help though, thank you :)

Comment: If he hasn't taught you how to use functions yet, you can just manually reset them to 0 at the bottom of the loop. That's a terrible way to do it, but it's the simplest. You'll need to learn functions eventually though

Comment: Thanks again, Carcigenicate. I found the solution with your help. I hope you have a good night.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) with the key as a String you can keep track of our counts in one object.  You then could put as many Maps, one for each test/string into a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).  Then you can loop over the list preforming the same test(s) on different data sets.

Being homework and all I'm not going to post any code.